# How to declare an argument as a function in SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj

my question goes like this:
how can I define a function , that receives a function without using type constraints or in other words, without having to type fun f1(f2:type->type) ?
I'm trying to think of a way that uses the argument f2 as a function but its not getting anywhere.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The one thing that you can do with a function that you can't do with any other value, is to call it. So using `f2` as a function means calling it - that is, applying it to an argument.

So for example you could define `f1` as:

```
fun f1 f2 = f2 42
```

and the inferred type of `f1` would be `(int -> 'a) -> 'a` (making the type of `f2` `int -> 'a`).

Comment: Thanks! however I was looking fora solution that includes polymorphic functions without having to use any specific number

Comment: @Basilm That was an example. You can call it with whichever argument you want.

Comment: I understand , but in your example you used an argument which is a number, something that does not have to be received as an argument.
I'm a beginner at SML , but if I wanted a polymorphic function doesn't it force me to receive an extra argument (a) so I can do f2 a?

Comment: @Basilm Yes, the only way to define a function of type `('a -> 'b) -> 'b` (which seems like what you're asking for now), or anything similar, would involve exceptions or infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

By returning an anonymous function, you can do this in such a way that the resulting function can take an arbitrary function for input (although not in a very useful way):

```
fun id f = fn x => f x
```

This makes `id` a higher-order function which returns its input function unmodified. The type of `id` is `fn : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b`

As an example of its "use":

```
- fun f x = x*x;
val f = fn : int -> int
- val g = id f;
val g = fn : int -> int
- g 5;
val it = 25 : int
```

A slightly more interesting example which will only work with functions of type `'a -> 'a`:

```
 fun self_compose f = fn x => f (f x)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I managed to compose what I was looking for , but I still dont understand , the format you mentioned is where a function receives a function and returns another function, but what if I want a function that receives a function : a->b and returns a function that receives a function : a->b and returns b?
In another words , the function type is : ('a->'b)->('a->'b)->'b

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible. A function of type `'a -> 'b` is a means of taking a value of type `'a` and mapping it to a value of type `'b`. So to get a value of the second type you need a value of the first type. You seem to want to find a way of getting a value of the second type directly from the function itself, without any actual input. That really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Don't know if it changes anything but the exact type I'm looking for  is :
('a->'b)->('a * 'b ->'b)->'b

Comment: I completely understand what you're saying, I cannot receive a result of type 'b without having an input for the function of type : 'a->'b , which is my problem. However I was asked to do that no matter what the function itself does , as long as its' type is the one I mentioned. ( I double checked )

Comment: I managed to work it out , the command for this was : fun h a = fn b => fn g => g(a,g(a,b));

Comment: @Basilm Nice solution.

Comment: Thank you mister.